# BNF grammar specification

Tags: grammar, bnf

Write a BNF specification where each string in the language starts with x’s followed by y’s followed by z’s, with the following constraint: number of occurrences of y is greater than the number of occurrences of x and z (|y| > |x|+|z|).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Start by trying the language where `|y|=|x|+|z|`. Then think about what needs to change to get more `y`s.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out eventually.
BNF specification :

<S"> --> <A'> <C'>

<A'> --> x<A'>yy | xyy

<C'> --> yy<C'>z | yyz

Comment: You can't build some valid strings with that specification like `y` or `xyyyz`.